# How to render Vue with Django

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm working on a small application using Vue.js and Django on Digitalocean, so I have installed Django Webpack loader and the tracker also, now I have executed my **Django server** and my vue.js also using **npm run serve**  and when I access to my webpage localhost:8000 I see only a blank page since everything is installed correctly, This is my HTML page ( when I inspect on chrome browser )

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Title of the document</title>  
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
            <div id="app"></div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/js/app.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    
 </html>
```

PS : i think the problem is in app.js  ( because i follow the link and i get an error )

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8080/js/app.js might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should config your vue application first creating vue.config.js file.
vue.config.js:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  // on Windows you might want to set publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
  publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: "./dist/",

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .plugin("BundleTracker")
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: "./webpack-stats.json" }]);

    config.output.filename("bundle.js");

    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

    config.resolve.alias.set("__STATIC__", "static");

    config.devServer
      // the first 3 lines of the following code have been added to the configuration
      .public("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
      .host("127.0.0.1")
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
      .https(false)
      .disableHostCheck(true)
      .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
  }

  // uncomment before executing 'npm run build'
  // css: {
  //     extract: {
  //       filename: 'bundle.css',
  //       chunkFilename: 'bundle.css',
  //     },
  // }
};
```

Then load render_bundle from webpack_loader. Your django template will be like:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- This part is in the screenshot at the bottom! -->
    <h1>Vue JS</h1>
    <div id="app"></div>
    {% render_bundle 'app' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

## Make Sure you are using webpack-bundle-tracker of version @0.4.3

You can follow [this link](https://dev.to/saymy__name__/hooking-up-django-and-vue-js-19j3) for step by step tutorial.

Comment: how can i load my javascript files and CSS

Comment: you can load css and js on django template. you can also add css and js on vue side as well